# Importing customer with names in Japanese - Required attribute 'firstname' has an empty value for all rows

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, importexport

I am trying to Import customers with their names in Japanese(katakana). It shows following error in validation results (On linux machine)

`Required attribute 'firstname' has an empty value in rows: 1,2,3,and so on`

The values are there in the column for firstname, but still it says empty value. If I enter English characters instead of Japanese, it accepts and does not show any error.

If I do the same thing on Windows OS, same file with Japanese characters works perfectly.

Not sure, if its a Magento's bug or I need to do something differently?

If anyone has a solution or any suggestion, please let me know

File format is .csv, Encoding utf-8

The contents of the file are:

```
email,_website,_store,firstname,lastname,password_hash,created_in,store_id,group_id,website_id,prefix,middlename,suffix,dob,taxvat,confirmation,gender,created_at,rp_token,rp_token_created_at,disable_auto_group_change,password,_address_firstname,_address_lastname,_address_country_id,_address_region,_address_postcode,_address_city,_address_street,_address_telephone,_address_fax,_address_company,_address_prefix,_address_middlename,_address_suffix,_address_vat_id,_address_default_billing_,_address_default_shipping_
john.doe@example.com,base,default,金魚,金魚,2049484a4020ed15d0e4238db22977d5:eg,,1,1,1,,,,,,,,"2007-08-31 00:23:13",,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Can you provide the first few lines of the file, just mix the letters to be ensure privacy. I have no clue of japanese, but your customer's customer's should be safe.

Comment: would be great if you can edit it into your question with the header :)

Comment: yea, let's dig into this...

Comment: Sorry :-) `File is valid! To start import process press "Import" button  Import`

Comment: In your case Magento must be installed on Windows, right?

Comment: No, I'm running on Mac OS X

Comment: ohh.. What must be wrong, right after installing magento on my linux server, I try to import same file and it says firstname and lastname are empty.

Comment: I can't reproduct on my linux server CentOS with apache and PHP 5.5.5

Comment: I guess you already have a customer with same email id, please change the email id of either existing customer or in the csv and then you would see the error

Comment: No, I have no customers in my table. Sorry, can't reproduce...

Comment: No problem, Thank you so much for trying :)

Comment: btw I have PHP version 5.3.3 on my linux server. Do you think it might be the issue?

Comment: Did you found the problem? I'm eager to hear about it.

Comment: Couldn't figure out the problem yet.. but have verified 2 things: 1. It works on Windows OS (php version, 5.3 or 5.5) 2. Does not work on Linux - (PHP version 5.3)

Comment: Seems like an encoding issue. Stepping through the code, where does it die out?

Comment: Have you checked your DB encoding? Make sure you're working with the DB in utf8_general_ci and not latin_swedish_XXX

Answer (score 1):

I can say for sure that this is an encoding problem (as most of the people suspect in the comments).
I tried with the sample provided in the question on Windows (PHP 5.3) and it works.
I tried on linux with PHP 5.3 and it works.

The encoding for the file I used is UTF-8 Without BOM.
Maybe that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The csv file encoding is UTF-8 without BOM (since I use notepad++, I could see it). Actually, the same file which works on local system(windows) does not work on server(linux) is a big problem. Maybe some server settings, i guess.

Comment: @Win8_learner. Like I said, it worked for me on linux. So I guess you might be on to something. Check the server settings. Unfortunately I don't have any ideas on where you can start on this. :(